# Bootstrap 3 typeahead.js - set form val

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I am using typeahead.js with Bootstrap 3 and using the code below it seems to work well to the point that I can get a dropdown with the `countryName` value from the json file but I now want to assign the `ID` to the input value attribute so I can submit the correct `countryID` rather than the displayed text.

My json file returns the following data  `[{"ID": 1, "countryName": "United States"},{"ID": 2, "countryName": "United Kingdom"},{"ID": 3, "countryName": "United Emirettes"}]`

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
    return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substrRegex;
    matches = [];
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
        console.log(str['countryName'])
      if (substrRegex.test(str['countryName'])) {
        matches.push({ value: str['countryName'] });
      }
    });
    cb(matches);
  };
};

$.getJSON("countries2.json",function(result){
   format: "json"
})
.done(function( data ) {
    $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 2
    },
    {
      name: 'countries',
      valueKey: 'countryName',
      displayKey: 'value',
      source: substringMatcher(data)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you change your subStringMatcher so that it gives also the country ID. In object add also key with value ID. Try this:

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
    return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substrRegex;
    matches = [];
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
        console.log(str['countryName'])
      if (substrRegex.test(str['countryName'])) {
        matches.push({ key:str['ID'], value: str['countryName'] });
      }
    });
    cb(matches);
  };
};
```

Then change typeahead options valueKey to key.

```
 $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({

  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 2
},
{
  name: 'countries',
  valueKey: 'key',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: substringMatcher(data)
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this answer. I can now see the ID coming through to the typehead function but when I submit the form the value being sent through is still the countryName. It appears valueKey is not doing anything